# Filtering filtered data

Tags: grails, filtering, criteria, grails-orm

I'm new to grails and MVC so please bear with me.

I have some links on my GSP that do some static filtering. For instance, the example below returns only
those `Request` domain class instances with status ***Open***. But I also want to be able to do some dynamic filtering on the same model (***results*** in the code bellow).

Use case would be something like this: User sees all `Request` domain class instances in the table. He clicks on the link ***Open requests*** and gets only those `Request` instances that have ***status*** property with value ***Open***. Than he sets `dateFrom` and `dateTo` using date picker control and clicks on the ***Filter*** button which calls the method/action that further filters data from the table. So it should return only those request that are opened and that are created within the specified period.

```
def openedRequests = {
    def contact = Contact?.findByUser(springSecurityService.currentUser)
    def productlines = contact.productlines()
    def requestCriteria = Request.createCriteria()      
    def results = requestCriteria.list {
        eq("status", "Open")
        and {
            'in'("productline",productlines)
        }

    }
    render(view:'supportList', model:[requestInstanceList:results, requestInstanceTotal: results.totalCount])
}
```

***EDIT***
On my GSP I have few links that call controller actions which perform some domain class instances filtering. For example I have OpenedRequests, ClosedRequests, NewRequests. But I also have some textboxes, comboboxes, datePicker controls for additional filtering. I call the filterRequests action with a button.

```
def filterRequests = {
    def contact = Contact?.findByUser(springSecurityService.currentUser)
    def productlines = contact.productlines()
    def requestCriteria = Request.createCriteria()
    def results = requestCriteria.list {
        if(params.fDateFrom && params.fDateTo){
            def dateFrom = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(params.fDateFrom_value)
            def dateTo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(params.fDateTo_value)
            between("dateCreated",dateFrom,dateTo)
        }
        if(params?.fStatus){
            eq("status",params.fStatus)
        }
        if(params?.fCompany){
            eq("company", params.fCompany)
        }
        and {'in'("productline",productlines)
        }
        if(params.sort != null && params.order !=  null){
            order(params.sort, params.order)
        }
    }
    render(view:'supportList', model:[requestInstanceList:results, requestInstanceTotal: results.totalCount])

}
```

I want to be able to filter Request instances with some of mentioned links and than if I set up some additional filters, for example dateFrom i dateTo with datePicker. I want those filters to be aware of previous filtering with link if there were any. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David suggested that I use Detached Criteria but I am using Grails 1.3.7 for my app. So, at the moment this isn't an option. I also thought of using database views and stored procedures but I wasn't sure how that will work with Grails (but that is something that I will definitely have to explore) and I wanted some results fast so I did something not very DRY. When I filter table with one of the mentioned links I save the name of the link/action in session and in filterRequest action (that does additional filtering) I check the session to see if there has been any previous 'link filtering' and if it were I apply those filters on the table with criteria, and after that I apply the filters that were manualy entered. I don't like it but that's all I came up with with my limited understanding of Grails. Below is my filterRequest action:

```
def filterRequests = {
    def contact = Contact?.findByUser(springSecurityService.currentUser)
    def productlines = contact.productlines()
    def requestCriteria = Request.createCriteria()
    def results = requestCriteria.list {
        if(session.filter == "newRequests"){
            and{
                isNull("acceptedBy")
                ne("status", "Closed")
            }
        }
        if(session.filter == "openRequests"){
            and{
                ne("status",'Closed')
            }
        }
        if(session.filter == "closedRequests"){
            and{
                eq("status", "Closed")
            }
        }   

        if(session.filter == "myRequests"){
            and{
                eq("acceptedBy", contact.realname)
            }
        }


        if(params.fDateFrom && params.fDateTo){
            def dateFrom = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(params.fDateFrom_value)
            def dateTo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(params.fDateTo_value)
            and{
                between("dateCreated",dateFrom,dateTo)
            }
        }
        if(params?.fAcceptedBy){
            and{
                eq("acceptedBy", params.fAcceptedBy)
            }
        }
        if(params?.fStartedBy){
            and{
                eq("startedBy", params.fStartedBy)
            }
        }
        if(params?.fCompany){
            and{
                ilike("company", "%" + params.fCompany +"%")
            }   
        }
        and {'in'("productline",productlines)
        }
        if(params.sort != null && params.order !=  null){
            order(params.sort, params.order)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DetachedCriterias](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0/guide/single.html#detachedCriteria) which where introduced with Grails 2.0.

A `DetachedCriteria` is independed from any session and can be reused easily:

```
def openRequests = new DetachedCriteria(Request).build {
     eq("status", "Open")
     and {
        'in'("productline",productlines)
     }
}
```

Then upon your next sub-filter request you can reuse the `DetachedCriteria` and perform a sub-query on it, like:

```
def results = openRequests.findByStartDateBetweenAndEndDateBetween(dateFrom, dateTo, dateFrom, dateTo)
```

Of course you have to remember somehow what the original query was (session, request param), to use the correct criteria as a basis for the sub-query.

(Disclaimer: I haven't yet tried detached criterias myself)

Comment: Thank you david. I understand that. But my question was somewhat different. I've updated the question so I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your updates. Hope this fits your problem?

Comment: David, thank you for your help and sorry for the delay. But for the moment my app is built with Grails 1.3.7. I will upgrade to 2.0 as soon as possible. And I will try out Detached Criteria this weekend and will post my experience. I've posted my answer.